# Toggle each button in a set of results

Tags: javascript, php, toggle

My search script lists 10 MP3 results from MySQL using `while`. I want to open a player when the user clicks the "play" button, then change the text to "stop".

Every thing is working fine in the following script, but it works only for the first result. If I click other results, they play the first result only. How can I toggle the "play/stop" buttons on all my search results?

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("player");
    var text = document.getElementById("playtext");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Play";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Stop";
    }
}
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){     
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
        $title = $results['title'];
        $download = $results['url'];
        $album = $results['album'];
        $size = $results['size'];

        echo '<div id="song_html">';
            echo '<div class="left">';
                echo $size;
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div id="right_song">';
                echo '<div style="font-size:15px;"><b>'.$title.'</b></div>';
                echo '<div style="font-size:12px;"><b>Movie : <a href=search.php?search='.urlencode($album).'><font color="blue">'.$album.'</font></a></b></div>';
                echo '<div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">';
                    echo '<div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;"><b><a href='.$download.'><font color="green">Download</font></a></b></div>';
                echo '</div>';  

                echo '<a id="playtext" href="javascript:toggle();">Play</a>';
                echo '<div id="player"><h1>Player</h1></div>';
            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#playtext
{
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left; 
    height:27px; 
    font-size:13px; 
    padding-top:4px;
}

#player
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: you are having multiple id's with the same name, that will make troubles with javascript. I would recommend you, if you can, to go with jQuery

Comment: Mysql is officially deprecated. Use Mysqli or PDO instead..

Comment: Add a counter or something to differentiate between different songs. Use that unique id in the toggle() function.

Comment: Not a PHP problem but a DOM problem as @Cheshire says. The JS doesn't know what button to change because you're pointing to several buttons at a time, so it only chooses to work on one of them.

Comment: Thank you,, Yest i try with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told before, the ID's are making it go wrong. Javascript detects more than one, an it will go only for the first match.

If you are going with jQuery, I recommend it, make the ID's, classes.

Then, inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`, you can create a `$(".the_class").on("click", function(){});` and insert there the toggle for what you need.